# call DLL from python

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, dllimport

I have a DLL and I want to call a function from python. The function signature is this:

```
StartJob(double vInp[], VARIANT vRis[], double *aOpt)
```

In python I'm using ctype for loading the DLL. I have never done these things so any advice will be useful to me. The question is: what are the correct types to pass to the function?
Now I'm passing

```
# input, output and flag array initialized
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\\Users\\utente25\\PycharmProjects\\dll\\test.dll')
arrIn = (ctypes.c_double * len(input))(*input)
arrOut = (ctypes.c_char * len(output))(*output)
arrFlag = (ctypes.c_double * len(flag))(*flag)
#Call function
res = lib.StartJob(arrIn, arrFlag, arrOut)
```

Comment: You are pass an array of double to an argument that expects array of VARIANT. Isn't that 
comtypes.automation.VARIANT. I'd be setting argtypes and restyle too.

Comment: what do you mean for restyle?

Comment: I was convinced that the signature was not correct instead the documentation of the dll was incomplete and some files were missing

Comment: `restype`, sorry my autocorrect did that!